# Convert PHP and JSON encode to a Javascript Date

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, date

All,
I'm creating some JSON arrays by looping through my database and populating some values. The code to do this is:

```
$return_arr = array();
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calendar_events"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array['start'] = $row['start'];
    $row_array['end'] = $row['end'];
    $row_array['allDay'] = $row['allDay'];
    $row_array['description'] = $row['description'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This works fine except it doesn't display the date correctly. When I find examples of ones that have a date display correctly it looks like this:

```
{
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
    allDay: false
}
```

How can I use PHP to format my date like this so it looks the same. My data is stored as a DATETIME in the database. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0)` is certainly not *JSON*. It's Javascript code.

Comment: you should pass through this and run something like `row.start = new Date(row.start);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 $row_array['start'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['start']));
 $row_array['end'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['end']));
```

Answer (score 1):

The dates being retrieved from MySQL (in the $row array) will be of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' as they are stored with the MySQL DATETIME type.

> *"The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format."* - [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types - MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

This format is one of the [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) of the [PHP DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). This means you can easily [construct a PHP DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) from your MySQL DATETIME value.

e.g. for your 'start' date

```
$start = new DateTime($row['start']);
```

You can then use the [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on your newly created DateTime object to print it out as a string in any format you like.

e.g. if you wanted to put the date into your $row_array in the form DD-MM-YYYY

```
$row_array['start'] = $start->format('d-m-Y');
```

Note also that it's recommended to use the [MySQL Improved Extension - mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) for connecting to a MySQL database.

> *"If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead."* - [php.net - mysqli overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use php's date() function to create the date string.

```
$dateStr = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

If you need to pass the js date object then this isn't the solution for you.